# Laravel comparing model date column with relation date column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to compare two date columns from different tables.

**Here's my model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ExitAccessionGood extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['exit_accession_id', 'norm_id', 'quantity'];

public function entry_goods()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\EntryAccessionGood', 'norm_id', 'norm_id');
}

public function packagings()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\PackagingItem', 'norm_id', 'norm_id');
}
}
```

The `entry_goods()` function gather all "norms" from the `entry_accession_goods` table that have the same `norm_id` as in the `exit_accession_goods` table.

```
public function entry_goods()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\EntryAccessionGood', 'norm_id', 'norm_id');
}
```

But it gathers all of them, however I only need the get the ones with the date less or equal to the model's table.

So for example, if there are norm ids 1 and 2 added in the `exit_accession_goods` table (yesterday), and the same ids (1 and 2) added today in the `entry_accession_goods` table (today), the function `entry_goods()` should NOT get the data from the `entry_accession_goods` table.

**This is what I tried:**

```
public function entry_goods()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\EntryAccessionGood', 'norm_id', 'norm_id')
    ->whereRaw('entry_accession_goods.created_at <= exit_accession_goods.created_at');
}
```

I'm unable to access the `exit_accession_goods.created_at` which is the problem, anyone know the solution? Thank you.

Comment: have you tried: `$model_name->entry_goods()->where('created_at', '<=', $other_model->created_at)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it as an eloquent query...

```
$date = 2020/01/01'
$var = ExitAccessionGood::whereHas('entry_good', function ($query) use ($date) {
        $query->where('created_at', '<', $date);
    })->get();
```

That should do what you want, assuming I understood the question

Comment: I don't have the date save inside a variable. I'm trying to compare two dates from different tables in one query. E.g. rows in `exit_accession_goods` created today should look at rows in `entry_accession_goods` that were made today or before it.  `->whereRaw('entry_accession_goods.created_at <= exit_accession_goods.created_at');`

Answer (score -1):

This Correct Relation

```
public function entry_goods(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\EntryAccessionGood', 'norm_id', 'norm_id')
    ->where(created_at <= $this->attributes['created_at']);
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a description of how your answer addresses the original posting. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: not working. giving Undefined index error